# For the construction phase why is selectionOrder=RANDOM so much faster than the default option?

Tags: optaplanner

Given the configuration below why is it so much faster when selectionOrder = RANDOM (7s) than when the default is used i.e. selectionOrder commented out (20min). Also when is the RANDOM order applied? Once at the start or at every step?

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <changeMoveSelector>
        <selectionOrder>RANDOM</selectionOrder>
        <selectedCountLimit>300</selectedCountLimit>
        <valueSelector variableName="user"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="startDate"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>

  </constructionHeuristic>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: `RANDOM` is so much faster, because it doesn't need to generate any sort of collection of items to iterate over. It simply generates a random item every time it is called. We do not need to know what comes before, or what comes after. If instead you want a curated selection with guarantees on repetition, we have to first enumerate all of the options. And that can take considerable amount of time. See [selection order](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#selectionOrder) for details.

To answer your second and third question, please check out [selector cache types](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#cacheType).

Comment: I'd argue it's the `<selectedCountLimit>300</>` that makes this so much faster. It cuts the the number of evaluated moves per step drastically. But that doesn't work well with Original. As for the selectionOrder: Original should be about just as fast as Random (or even faster).

Comment: If that is the case, then it doesn't appear to be the case here. And it would be interesting to have the opportunity to see the code and investigate why.

Comment: Here is a link to the source - it's vs code project.

[link](https://tqsintegration.sharefile.com/d-s7e1f87286c4140a2a1bb64de1c2942d7)

Comment: If you are interested in only a specific part of the code I can pull that out. Thanks in advance.

There are only 300 users so it's not clear to me why selectedCountLimit = 300 would have such a dramatic effect.

Comment: What I am looking for is a piece of code that I can directly run, which will show me the problem. Code snippets are often useful, but not in this case - I need something that reproduces the problem in practice.

Comment: Please find demo solution at this location which hopefully should allow you see the behaviour. Switching to selection order = RANDOM returns much fast.

[Demo Solution Code](https://tqsintegration.sharefile.com/d-sdca3757b04204e908e9535de37fa3215)

Apologies for only coming back to this now - have been working on other topics.